# Context of this when triggering method on root from child

Tags: knockout.js

I have this very simple test view

```
<button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
<table data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td><button data-bind="click: $root.remove">Remove</button></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6PP5m/

The problem is that the context of this in the remove method is the child view model that fired the click event

I havent found a solution that I like, you can  add a self variable in the contructor and use that instead of "this", but its more clean code and OO to use the "this" keyword

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qn2CM/

You can also create a proxy function delegate but its still not very clean code

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gYhMr/

What I would like is to tell ko somehow to set the context of this to the correct correct scope ($root in this case) is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click/event bindings run in the context of the current data as you have found.

There are a few options to ensure that your function runs with the correct context:

- set the correct `this` to a variable like `self` and use it in your handler (as you have mentioned)
- use something like `$.proxy` or `.bind` in your view model to ensure that `this` is correct (as you have mentioned)
- bind the function in-line like `data-bind="click: $root.remove.bind($root)"`
- use an (ugly) anonymous function like `data-bind="click: function() { $root.remove($data); }"`

Comment: Thanks! I think I like the third option best.

Comment: We used to go with the `self = this` workaround but now with ES6 classes this is is no longer the path we want to take. Since this post is from 2012, I'm wondering if these options are still the only/best/practical workarounds?