# 'this' scope with ES6 and Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6

I'm having an issue with the 'this' scope when using ES6.

Here´s a link to my [original and transpiled code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myArray%20%3D%20ko.observableArray(%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.removeFromArrayWithArrowFunction%20%3D%20value%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myArray.remove(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20removeFromArray(value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myArray.remove(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) with BabelJS.

When calling a function to remove an item from an array the scope of 'this' is undefined.

How can I make this to make this without redefining this (*let self = this*)?

```js
"use strict";

var _createClass = (function() {
  function defineProperties(target, props) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      var descriptor = props[i];
      descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
      descriptor.configurable = true;
      if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
      Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    }
  }
  return function(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
    if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
    if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
    return Constructor;
  };
})();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
  if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  }
}

var Point = (function() {
  function Point() {
    var _this = this;

    _classCallCheck(this, Point);

    this.myArray = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    this.removeFromArrayWithArrowFunction = function(value) {
      _this.myArray.remove(value);
    };
  }

  _createClass(Point, [{
    key: "removeFromArray",
    value: function removeFromArray(value) {
      this.myArray.remove(value);
    }
  }]);

  return Point;
})();

ko.applyBindings(new Point());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(myArray)"></span>
<h2>Issues with this scoping when using a regular Function</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: myArray">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.removeFromArray"></a>

  </li>
</ul>

<h2>Works as expected using an arrow function</h2>
<ul data-bind="foreach: myArray">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.removeFromArrayWithArrowFunction"></a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not really an ES6 problem, you're binding the `click` event to an object's method.  You're losing the context of `this`.  You need to bind the method to the parent object.

Comment: Thank you @JeffMercado. Any recommendation on how to achieve it?

Comment: sroes provided an ES6 solution. Otherwise, use any of the approaches outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737494/context-of-this-when-triggering-method-on-root-from-child).

Answer (score 2):

If you use viewmodel functions directly in your bindings, you're losing the context of `this` like Jeff Mercado explained. [Arrow functions capture the `this` value of the enclosing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this), so if you use the arrow function notation, you don't have to worry about `var self = this`.

So change the following:

```
removeFromArray(value) {
  this.myArray.remove(value);
}
```

Into:

```
removeFromArray = (value) => {
  this.myArray.remove(value);
}
```

And it should work fine.

[See babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Point%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myArray%20%3D%20ko.observableArray(%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.removeFromArrayWithArrowFunction%20%3D%20value%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myArray.remove(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20removeFromArray%20%3D%20(value)%20%3D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myArray.remove(value)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Please add an explanation to your solution, in particular that you are making use of a proposal for ES7. This is not ES6. Also, your solution is basically what the OP did with `this.removeFromArrayWithArrowFunction = value => { this.myArray.remove(value);}`.

Comment: You're right @FelixKling. I tried this locally and it didn't work since I'm not using the experimental Babel Features. Any other options?

Comment: Just what the OP already did, setting the function inside the constructor.

Comment: @FelixKling do you know what is the name of the feature proposal that enables this sintax in ES7? Thanks in advance

Comment: @CarlosMendes: "Class properties" https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb